# Import own class file in .java

Tags: java, class, import

Hey an question i have this compiled .class file that contains in the .java file this:

```
package my.mypackage;
public class MyClass {
//SPACE START
    public static void space(int spacecount) {
    int spacepos = 1;
        while (spacepos <= spacecount) {
            System.out.println("");
            spacepos++;
        }
    }
//SPACE END
//HASH START
    public static int encrypt(String pass) {
        int total = 0;
        int  countone = 0;
        int  counttwo = 0;
        String charlist = "abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        for (int l = 0; l < pass.length(); l++) {
            countone = pass.charAt(l);
            counttwo = (charlist.indexOf(countone));
            counttwo++;
            total *= 17;
            total += counttwo; 
        }
        return total;
    }
//HASH END
}
```

and i want to to import it into an other file named a.java it contains this:

```
import my.mypackage.MyClass;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class a {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass.space(4);
        Scanner in = new Scanner();
        System.out.println("Input pass: ");
        String a = in.nextLine();
        int b = MyClass.encrypt(a);
        MyClass.space(4);
        System.out.println(b);

    }
}
```

both are in one folder.
but when im trying to compile it it shows me this:

```
a.java:1: error: package my.mypackage does not exist                                                                                                                                  
import my.mypackage.MyClass;                                                                                                                                                          
                   ^                         
a.java:5: error: cannot access MyClass                                                                                                                                                
                MyClass.space(4);                                                                                                                                                     
                ^                                                                                                                                                                     
  bad class file: ./MyClass.class                                                                                                                                                     
    class file contains wrong class: my.mypackage.MyClass                                                                                                                             
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.                                                                                               
2 errors
```

can anyone show me how to bring it together step by step ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the culprit:

> both are in one folder.

Java compiler relies on a convention of naming source files and folders in a way that lets it find the source code by examining only the names of files, i.e. without checking their content; package name is part of the naming convention. That is why the compiler expects to find `MyClass.java` in a different folder.

Since `class MyClass` is in the `my.mypackage` package, while `class a` is in the default package, their `.java` files must not be placed in the same folder. Instead, `MyClass.java` file needs to be placed in the `my/mypackage/` (on Windows, `my\mypackage\`) folder in relation to the `a.java` file's location.

Comment: that means if my a.java file is in the folder `C:\JAVA\` the MyClass has to be in `C:\JAVA\my\myclass\` ?

Comment: how is it when i pack both in the package `my` ?

Comment: @Ch3t0r "that means if my a.java file is in the folder `C:\JAVA` the `MyClass.java` has to be in `C:\JAVA\my\myclass`?" Absolutely (except that you typed `myclass` instead of `mypackage`). "how is it when i pack both in the package `my`?" All `.java` files from the same package need to go in the same folder - in this case, that would be `C:\JAVA\my`.

Comment: okay now i now what i do wrong. The `CLASSPATH` variable had the value `"."` not `.` problem fixed.